# Inherited Properties not working

Tags: objective-c, ios, inheritance, protocols

I am having issues getting something to work in objective c.  I have the following protocol:

```
@protocol PFItem <NSObject>

- (NSNumber *)weight;
- (NSNumber *)cost;

@end
```

This protocol is implemented in the following class:

```
@interface PFItemObject : NSObject <NSCoding, PFItem> {
    NSString *name;
    NSNumber *weight;
    NSNumber *cost;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSNumber *weight;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSNumber *cost;
@property (readonly) NSString *className;

+ (id)itemWithString:(NSString *)string;

@end
```

Now, this works well for me, except when I use the PFItemObject as a superclass like so:

```
@interface PFWeaponObject : PFItemObject <NSCoding, PFItem> {
    NSString *damage;
    NSString *critical;
    NSString *range;
    NSNumber *attackBonus;
    NSNumber *damageBonus;
    WeaponTypes type;
    BOOL isTwoHanded;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *damage;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *critical;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *range;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSNumber *attackBonus;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSNumber *damageBonus;
@property WeaponTypes type;
@property BOOL isTwoHanded;

+ (PFWeaponObject *)unarmedWeapon;

@end
```

The `+itemWithString:` method, in the `PFWeaponObject` works like this:

```
+ (id)itemWithString:(NSString *)string {
    NSArray *components = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
    PFWeaponObject *weapon = [[PFWeaponObject alloc] init];

    [weapon setName:[components objectAtIndex:0]];
    [weapon setWeight:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[components objectAtIndex:1] floatValue]]];
    [weapon setCost:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[components objectAtIndex:2] intValue]]];
    [weapon setDamage:[components objectAtIndex:3]];
    [weapon setCritical:[components objectAtIndex:4]];
    [weapon setRange:[components objectAtIndex:5]];
    [weapon setType:[[components objectAtIndex:6] integerValue]];
    [weapon setAttackBonus:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[components objectAtIndex:7] intValue]]];
    [weapon setDamageBonus:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[components objectAtIndex:8] intValue]]];
    [weapon setIsTwoHanded:[[components objectAtIndex:9] boolValue]];

    return [weapon autorelease];  
}
```

I assumed that, because I have inherited from the PFItemObject, I should be able to assign values to the superclass' properties without problem.  But when I do the following:

```
- (void)testItemCreationStrings {
    NSString *weaponString = @"+1 Greatsword;25;2500;2d6;x3;Melee;5;1;1;YES";
    PFWeaponObject *sampleWeapon = [PFWeaponObject itemWithString:weaponString];
}
```

All properties from the superclass (`PFItemObject`) all return `@"+1 Greatsword"`.  Did I miss something somewhere that I should have done?

Thanks for any help you can provide, and please, feel free to ask for more information if you need it.

Comment: Are you really overwriting the name property in your real code?  That is, [weapon setName: [...]] is called three times in a row.

Comment: No, I just copy/pasted incorrectly.  I have corrected it in my question.

Comment: You might want to post real code.  Presumably, the mismatch of a class method declaration and an instance method definition is wrong, along with cost being "objectAtIndex:0".

Comment: Ok, so I updated it by copy/pasting the code directly from Xcode.  This is exactly what is being run right now.

Comment: How do you synthesize/define property methods?

Comment: `@synthesize [property name]`.  It's done for each property in the implementation file for each class.

Comment: One more question, how are you detecting that there's a problem? (I've created classes based on your code in a test app and found that `NSLog(@"%@, %@, %@", sampleWeapon.name, sampleWeapon.weight, sampleWeapon.cost);` at the end of the test method shows the expected values.)

Comment: I am looking at the 'Variables View' in xcode

Comment: Ok, so what gives, when I look at the 'variable view' I get the wrong values, but when I write to the NSLog as you did, it comes out correctly.  Is this an issue that I need to worry about for future reference, or just go with what the NSLog tells me?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Edit because the question was edited. I think I have a solution.

Try this:

```
+ (id)itemWithString:(NSString *)string {
    NSArray *components = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
    PFWeaponObject *weapon = [[PFWeaponObject alloc] init];

    [weapon setName:[components objectAtIndex:0]];
    [weapon setWeight:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[components objectAtIndex:1] intValue]]];
    [weapon setCost:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[components objectAtIndex:2] intValue]]];
    // etc.
    // etc.
}
```

I think you are not setting the behavior and format of the NSNumberFormatter, and I also think that using it is unnecessary. There are other examples of how to use number formatters if you really want to do it that way for some reason. If there is a reason you want/need to, I can provide direction.

Comment: Well now, I didn't check the NSString reference to see that I could do that.  Thanks bunch for that (now I don't have to create so many number formatters, lol).  Unfortunately, the problem still persists.